# How to update value in angular xeditable?

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I have a big block like:
[app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vAsB.jpg)

In some cases underlined data (wich is xeditable text) can be updated from controller. After this as is expected - $scope value updates (i tested it by passed expression in {{}} near xeditable) but value inside xeditable not change.
How can i update it manually or is it a way to auto update value inside angular xeditable when $scope value is updated?

Comment: Any ideas?.....

Comment: so sad.........

Comment: did you find any solution to this?